# foreach doesn't look like working properly in php

Tags: php, sql, foreach

I used following code to get the total price, but it outputs value that is higher than the expected value. What would be the reason for this?

```
$query =  " SELECT *
            FROM `mytable`
            WHERE `sale_id` = $id";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$item =  mysql_fetch_array($result);


foreach ($item as $row) {            
    $total_price += $row['price']; 
}

echo $total_price;
```

Comment: Have a look at what [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array) actually does.

Comment: I did that, but not work, out put the same value.

Comment: sum your in your sql query

Comment: @Gumbo So do you think using while is the best here ha?

Comment: The manual says: “Fetch **a result row** as an associative array, a numeric array, or both.” Just look at the examples.

Comment: @Mubo no I need to do some more calculation inside the foreach this is just the trial.

Comment: It's not about while being the best here, its about how mysql_fetch_array works to provide the next entry which is what youre missing. Also you can resume a lot of work with `"SELECT SUM(price) FROM \`mytable\` WHERE \`sale_id\` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($id) . "'";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {            
    $total_price += $row['price']; 
}

echo $total_price;
```